# Random.nextInt Bounds exception

Tags: android, kotlin

I, am using in my Android app many times fun nextInt.

```
RandomNumber = Random.nextInt(0, Answears.size)
```

Here is part of documentation:
fun nextInt(from: Int, until: Int): Int
Gets the next random Int from the random number generator in the specified range.
Generates an Int random value uniformly distributed between the specified from **(inclusive)** and until **(exclusive)** bounds.
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.random/-random/next-int.html

Recently In production I have started to see error:

```
Caused by java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 11, size is 11
       at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
       at app7soft.tabliczka_mnozenia.nauka1.Ucz(nauka1.kt:300)
```

Caused in this line:

```
UserAnswears.add(Answears[RandomNumber].dropLast(1) + N4.text.toString())
```

My suspicion is that in some android versions or Phones **until** is inclusive not exclusive causing this issue.

Anybody can help ?

Comment: Any concurrent modification of the `Answears` list? E.g. some other piece of code removing elements after you've computed the index.

Comment: "My suspicion is that in some android versions or Phones until is inclusive not exclusive causing this issue." Can't be, the Kotlin standard library is shipped with your app.

Comment: Thanks for comments. If its not possible that it depends from Phone/Android Version I need to debug more my code. Maybe there is some concurrent modification. Need to check....

Comment: It would be simpler to just use `Answears.random()` anyway.

Comment: You should just use `RandomNumber = Random.nextInt(0, Answears.size - 1)`